# How do I inspect local variables of a method using ASM?

Tags: java

How do I inspect local variables of a method using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)? I understand that this is not possible using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html

> If "Link with editor" is on, then any selection in Java editor will be
>   followed with selection of appropriated bytecode label, and vice -
>   versa.

**Note:** this bi-directional selection could only works, if your bytecode contains source lines/local variables information. Check your compiler setings, if you are not sure that your compiler generates debug information.

If "`show raw bytecode`" is off, than local variable names will be shown instead of indexes, full qualified names replaced with simply class names, and primitive type abbreviations decoded to readable names.

If "`show current element only`" is on, then only bytecode of current field/method node will be shown (if cursor is placed inside field/method name or body).

More Details given in [author home page](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html)(source).